# How to install dlib module for python 3.8 (32-bit)?

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-module, dlib

I need to install dlib module for python 3.8 (32-bit) version. Remember for 32-bit not the 64-bit

I researched and found that we could install with binary file ( I found in GitHub) but there was no binary file for the 32-bit version. It was only for the 64-bit.

How can I install it?

Comment: Is there an error if you install it via `pip install dlib==19.22.0`?